# How to refer to a DIV tag in a PHP page from another PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two .php pages and I want to know how can I refer  tag of a php page in the print("location.href = 'eod.php'"); of second page. If I try the above code it's taking me to the home page of page1.php, but it need to display the  of page1.php. Please suggest me.

For example:

```
page1.php
page2.php
```

In page1.php I have several  attributes. Now I would like to know how to refer to a particular `<div>` element of page1.php page from page2.php.

Here is my sample code.

**div tag of Page1.php:**

```
<div  id="#incidentform2">
    <hi>Incident Final Details</h1>
    <!-- other markup -->               
</div>
```

**code in page2.php:**

```
<?php
include("include/adminclude.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $emailid=$_POST['emailid'];
    $incidentno=$_POST['incidentno'];
    $startdate=$_POST['startdate'];
    //$type=$_POST['type'];
    //$priority=$_POST['priority'];

    $sa="insert into eod_master(emailid,incidentno,startdt)
        VALUES('$emailid','$incidentno','$startdate')";

    $aq=mysql_query($sa);

    if($aq)
    {
        print("<script language='javascript'>location.href = 'eod.php'</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        print("<script language='javascript'>location.href = 'warning.php'</script>");
    }

}
?>
```

Now it's taking me to home page of page1.php. But I want to know how to refer to the particular `<div>` of a php page in `print("<script language='javascript'>location.href = 'eod.php'</script>");`

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the use of the [anchor](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) ?

```
<script language='javascript'>location.href = 'eod.php#incidentform2'</script>
```

In your example I noticed an error, you don't need the anchor in the id attributes :

```
<div  id="incidentform2">
   <h1>Incident Final Details</h1>
                           ...........
                           ..................               
</div>
```

Comment: tried it. But it still taking me to the home page of eod.php

Comment: anchor is working if my page one is a .html page, but it's not working with .php page

Comment: It's a little strange, because the PHP part is just the language that the server interpet. Then the server sends the HTML content back to the browser.

I wondered why you do your redirects with javascript? There is the header function in php :

header('Location: page.php');

Comment: using header, redirect functions I am able to redirect it to a php page. But I want to redirect it to a specific DIV tag of a php page